# How can I restore the state of a NativeScript application with App.Bundle?

Tags: nativescript

I'm attempting to restore the state of an application so that even if you press the home button on android, the app persists.

I have tried extending the activity class following native scripts guidelines but I'm stuck on extending after typing super.onCreate NativeScript application crashes and says that super can't be used here.

```
const MainActivity = android.app.Activity.extend("org.nativescript.forcefield.MainActivity",  {
    onCreate: function(savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    }
});

applicationModule.android.on(applicationModule.AndroidApplication.saveActivityStateEvent, (args) => {
    console.log('Event: ' + args.eventName + ', Activity: ' + args.activity + ' , Bundle: ' + args.bundle);
    lastPage = args.bundle;
});
```

I'm unable to get anything out of args.bundle. If I could just restore the state with that it would be lovely.

Comment: Which version of {N} you are using? Since 5.x you are suppose to extend AppCompatActivity. Moreover you are using `super` keyword which is TypeScript syntax but you are extending in traditional JavaScript way. Also, unless you call the activity callbacks as showcased in [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity#extending-activity) you are going to loose any application level events.

Comment: By keeping the app persistent, you mean preventing it from going to background when home button is pressed?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is that if the home button is pressed, then the app loses what's in the textfield for example. I'm trying to prevent that. I'm using the latest NS so should I extend AppCompatActivity?

Comment: Hmm, it may happen only if you are setting the textfield value upon load event. Generally the value should be retained. Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?